# How do i know Apache Load Balancer is working properly?

Tags: apache, tomcat

Hello i mean how do i guarantee Load balance is balancing it right is there any tool to prove it ?I need to prove it is balancing right but i have heard there is an tool to do that got any suggestion? I HAVE TRIED APACHE BENCHMARK tool but didn't show what i wanted

Comment: Define "balancing it right". Once you know what behaviour you *want* to see, you can easily check that it's what you *actually* see.

Comment: is there any administrative tools to monitor like how did that balancing happen

Answer (score 0):

In Mod_jk the is a worker of type status you can add to your config:

In your workers.properties:

```
worker.list=balancer,lbstats

worker.node1.type=ajp13
...
worker.node2.type=ajp13
...

worker.balancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.lbstats.type=status
```

In your httpd.conf:

```
JkMount /modjkstatus  lbstats
```

When the server is running, you can access a status page, displaying some cluster and balancer informaion, at your_server:8080/modjkstatus